# Dependency Tracker integration with DefectDojo not working

Tags: owasp-dependency-track

We use Dependency Tracker ver4.10.0 and DefectDojo ver 2.29.1
I'm trying to sent results to DefectDojo, but see no results.

In DefectDojo I've created project and engagement:

[DefectDojo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6s1s.png)

In Dependency tracker I've created integration:

[Dependency Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnkyI.png)

For project i've crated property:

[Project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwMRd.png)

However I see no results in DefectDojo and see no errors in Dependency Track.

How can I check and fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, are you sure your Dependency Track instance is able to reach your DefectDojo instance? It might be a network issue so may be worth checking the Dependency Track logs.